# radio button must not be already checked in zend form

Tags: zend-framework

I have to made radio buttons in zend form. I have used below code:-

```
$GiftEscalated = new Zend_Form_Element_Radio('IsEscalated'); 

$GiftEscalated->setLabel('Gift Escalated')

        ->setRequired(false)

        ->addFilter('StripTags')

        ->addFilter('StringTrim')

        ->addMultiOptions(array('Yes','No'))

        ->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper',

                            'Description',

                            'Errors',

                            array(array('data'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td')),

                            array('Label', array('tag' => 'td')),

                            array(array('row'=>'HtmlTag'),array('tag'=>'tr', 'openOnly'=>true))

                            ));
```

Its working. displaying radio buttons but one button is already checked. I don't want that. I want that radio buttons must not be already checked.

Please help.

Comment: Maybe you could check-boxes?  Not exactly clear on the selection logic you want but check-boxes with validation logic might work better.  Otherwise you can use radio and add a 'none' of 'none of the above' option.  **Radio**: *Only one value in a group may be selected, does not allow toggling off individual inputs*  Ref: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/13511/why-is-it-impossible-to-deselect-html-radio-inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi-options should be an associative array, so you want:

```
->addMultiOptions(array('yes' => 'Yes', 'no' => 'No'))
```

instead of what you currently have (the key there is the value that gets submitted, so change as needed).

If you want 0 and 1 submitted, then this will be a little clearer:

```
->addMultiOptions(array('0' => 'Yes', '1' => 'No'))
```

but you'll need to remove the two filters (which don't really serve any purpose anyway).

I think the issue is that your form will currently be using '0' as the value for the first element, which with the trim filters will equate to null, which is the value the form has initially.